# I am using textArea in my actionsheet the issue that i am facing is when i am typing the current value and action sheet keeps flickring in ios

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I encountering an issue with the TextArea component in my iOS app when used within an action sheet from Native Base. The problem is that when I type in the TextArea, the action sheet keeps flickering. However, when I replace the TextArea with an Input component, it works fine. I've also tried using TextInput and other action sheet libraries, but I faced the same problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Lu7.png)

```
       <Actionsheet
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={onClose}
>
        <Actionsheet.Content>
          <Actionsheet.Item>
            <Text style={styles.Heading2}>Add Feedback</Text>
          </Actionsheet.Item>
          <Box width="90%">
            <Text color="#c7c7c7">Description</Text>
            <TextArea
              multiline={true}
              h={40}
              borderColor="#F6F6F6"
              mt={3}
              bg="#F6F6F6"
              rounded={16}
              value={texts}
              onChangeText={(text) => setSomeTexts(text)}
            />
          </Box>

          <Box width="90%" mt={6}>
            <Text style={styles.btnTextTab}>Upload File</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={handleUpload}
              style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderStyle: 'dashed',
                borderColor: '#c7c7c7',
                borderRadius: 16,
                padding: 25,
                marginTop: 10,
                backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
              }}>
              <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: '#c7c7c7'}}>
                Upload file here
              </Text>
              <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: '#c7c7c7'}}>
                Tap to select file
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Box>
          {file ? (
            <Box width="90%" mt={6}>
              <HStack
                justifyContent="space-between"
                px={5}
                alignItems="center"
                h="56px"
                bg="#D1EDBF"
                rounded="13px">
                <Text bold color="black">
                  {file.name}
                </Text>
                <SvgXml
                  xml={trash}
                  w={18}
                  h={18}
                  onPress={() => setSelectedDocument(null)}
                />
              </HStack>
            </Box>
          ) : null}
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={handleAdd}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            style={{
              width: '90%',
              height: 55,
              backgroundColor: '#31251D',
              marginVertical: 20,
              borderRadius: 13,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: 'white'}}>send</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Actionsheet.Content>
      </Actionsheet>
```